# Count appearance of each player by groups in Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

There is a dataframe of players playing in different Teams(groups), so I need to count all intersections of each player with his team players where he only appears.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({ 'Team' : ['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C'],
                      'Player' : ['Joe', 'Mike', 'Steve', 'Henry', 'Steve', 'Joe', 'Mike', 'Joe', 'Steve', 'Dan', 'Henry']
                  })
df
Out[6]:
Player  Team
0   Joe     A
1   Mike    A
2   Steve   A
3   Henry   B
4   Steve   B
5   Joe     B
6   Mike    C
7   Joe     C
8   Steve   C
9   Dan     C
10  Henry   C
```

The output has to be like this. P.S I did it manually, so can be mistakes.

```
Joe Mike 2
Joe Steve 3
Joe Henry 2
Joe Dan 1

Mike Joe 2
Mike Steve 2
Mike Dan 1
Mike Henry 1

Steve Joe 3
Steve Mike 2
Steve Henry 2
Steve Henry 1

Henry Steve 2
Henry Joe 2
Henry Mike 1
Henry Dan 1

Dan Steve 1 
Dan Mike 1
Dan Joe 1
Dan Henry 1
```

**Explaining**: Joe has appeared in all 3 Teams, so I just count his intersections with other players between 3 Teams where he appeare. At the same time, Dan is only in Team C and I take into considereation only intersections with other players in Team C.

I tried to do it via groupby and cartesian product join but couldn't figure out how to combine it. May someone help to solve this task?

```
gp = df.groupby('Player')['Team'].apply(lambda x: "%s" % ', '.join(x)).to_frame()

index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([gp.index, gp.index], names = ["a", "b"])

new_df = pd.DataFrame(index = index).reset_index()
```

Comment: I think a starting point is `df.merge(df, on='Team')` to get your cross join, then applying `.groupby(['Player_x', 'Player_y']).Team.size()` should be close to what you want you'll want to drop identical X and Y players from it.

Comment: @Jon Clements♦ all works fine. Leave the comment and I'll approve it. Thanks a lot. The only difference is that needed to remove the same pairs (Joe-Joe m Henry-Henry etc)

Comment: I'm just back at  desk briefly... I'll see if I can't actually write up an actual answer - bear with :)

Comment: At any convenient moment write the answer and I'll approve it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given your input DF of:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({ 
    'Team' : ['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C'],
    'Player' : ['Joe', 'Mike', 'Steve', 'Henry', 'Steve', 'Joe', 'Mike', 'Joe', 'Steve', 'Dan', 'Henry']
})
```

You can merge it against itself on the "Team" column to get your cross-join, filter out the same named players in both columns, then take the number of teams that are between the pairs, eg:

```
new_df = (
    # Cartesian join dropping identical player pairs
    df.merge(df, on='Team')[lambda row: row.Player_x != row.Player_y]
    # Count unique number of overlaps and make column name a bit more usefu
    .groupby(['Player_x', 'Player_y']).Team.size().rename('shared_teams')
    # Optionally drop the index if not of use...
    .reset_index()
)
```

This'll give you:

```
   Player_x Player_y  shared_teams
0       Dan    Henry             1
1       Dan      Joe             1
2       Dan     Mike             1
3       Dan    Steve             1
4     Henry      Dan             1
5     Henry      Joe             2
6     Henry     Mike             1
7     Henry    Steve             2
8       Joe      Dan             1
9       Joe    Henry             2
10      Joe     Mike             2
11      Joe    Steve             3
12     Mike      Dan             1
13     Mike    Henry             1
14     Mike      Joe             2
15     Mike    Steve             2
16    Steve      Dan             1
17    Steve    Henry             2
18    Steve      Joe             3
19    Steve     Mike             2
```

Note - it might be more efficient to drop the duplicated names after grouping rather than before so.